# Alternative for `:has()` css class

Tags: html, css, web, css-selectors

The HTML code:

```
<label class="switch">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="form-check-label form-label"></label>
  </div>
  <span class="switch__slider switch__round"></span>
</label>
```

I need to change the CSS of the **switch__slider** when the **form-check-input** is checked

at the moment I am using

```
.switch .form-check:has(input:checked) + switch__slider {
    background-color: #2196F3; 
}
```

But I just found out it's not a good idea to use `:has()` class yet because it's still experimental from what I understood.

But I can't find another solution, any ideas?

Comment: JavaScript seems to be the only alternative at the moment, prior to [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) there was no CSS solution to this problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas and for now it's best not to use the `:has()` class selector right?

Comment: Use it by all means, just be prepared to have, and apply, an alternative solution for those browsers that don't (yet) implement it. Also, it's worth pointing out that nesting [`<label>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) is not permitted in valid HTML.

Comment: I see, well thanks, and thanks for pointing out that nest label is not permitted, I am using a python library that auto generates that part so I can't really do anything about that but learned something new!

Comment: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=has) page 83.9% users' browser support `:has()`